# Soot: soot.jimple.JimpleBody cannot be cast to soot.dava.DavaBody

Tags: java, classcastexception, soot

I ran the following code to get the exception handler in .class file:

```
public void getException(SootMethod method){
    DavaBody db = (DavaBody) method.retrieveActiveBody();
    IterableSet excepFacts = db.get_ExceptionFacts();
    Iterator<ExceptionNode> it = excepFacts.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        ExceptionNode en = it.next();
        ...
    }
}
```

I got errors after running above code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
soot.jimple.JimpleBody cannot be cast to soot.dava.DavaBody
```

The method `method.retrieveActiveBody()` returns **Body** type, not **JimpleBody**, so why is this error happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [documentation](https://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/doc/soot/SootMethod.html), `public Body retrieveActiveBody()` is:

> Returns the active body if present, else constructs an active body and returns that.

Let's look at the `Body` class:

```
public abstract class Body
extends AbstractHost
implements Serializable
```

So it is `Abstract` class, and by your exception, it returns `JimpleBody`, subclass of `Body`.

If `Rabbit` is `Animal`, and `Wolf` is also `Animal`, `Rabbit` is not a `Wolf`.

You can edit code like that:

```
if (method.retrieveActiveBody() instanceof JimpleBody) {

} else if (method.retrieveActiveBody() instanceof DavaBody) {

} else if (method.retrieveActiveBody() instanceof BafBody) {

} else if (method.retrieveActiveBody() instanceof StmtBody) {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Body is the declared type. In your configuration of Soot, it actually returns a JimpleBody.